# Event in Global.asax file that fires only for once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events

In MVC Global.asax file, we can see the `Application_Start` where this event fires only for once. But the session is not yet active/available here. So my question is, is there any event in Global.asax file that fired only for once and session is available also?
The reason I ask this is because, I use `ExpandoObject`
e.g.:

```
    public static dynamic Data
    {
        get
        {
            #region FAILSAFE
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[datakey] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[datakey] = new ExpandoObject();
            }
            #endregion

            return (ExpandoObject)HttpContext.Current.Session[datakey];
        }
    }
```

I want to initialize all of my ExpandoObject at once with the value of null:

```
MyExpando.Data.UserInformation = null;  
MyExpando.Data.FolderInformation = null;
```

That's why I'm looking for an event that only fired once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Will fire once when a new user session is created.

    // Contrary to Application_Start this event could run multiple
    // times during the AppDomain lifetime but that will ensure you 
    // that all users have the required data stored into the session.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the Session Start Event you are looking for..